# Writing to a text file with Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, text

I have this function if a button is pressed. It should write the data to a text file. I have this:

```
void contactenlijst_dialog::on_pushButton_2_released()
{
    QString werknemernaam, werknemermail, totaal;

    werknemernaam = ui->werknemer_input->text();
    werknemermail = ui->mail_input->text();

    if (werknemernaam == "" || werknemermail == "")
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(0,"Foutmelding","U heeft één of meerdere van de vereiste vakken niet ingevuld!");
    }

    else
    {
        QFile Files("://contactenlijst.txt");
        Files.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
        QTextStream textStream(&Files);
        totaal = "\n" + werknemernaam + "\t" + werknemermail;
        textStream << totaal;
        this->ui->werknemer_input->clear();
        this->ui->mail_input->clear();
        Files.close();
    }
}
```

I do not get any errors but it doesnt write anything to the text file. How do i get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: "I do not get errors" - that's probably because you don't check for them. Check the return value of open() and call errorString(). The path you pass is a Qt resource path - which is read-only.

Comment: Alright, I used a absolute path now but it also erases everything if something is written to it.

Comment: That's the default behavior when opening a file for writing. Add `| QIODevice::Append` to append to the already existing file.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't notation `":/filename.txt"` that it should not open a regular file, but a resource embedded inside executable? - see [Using Resources in the Application](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/resources.html#using-resources-in-the-application) section of the qt manual.

If that's what you are doing, then you shouldn't be able to open such file for writing - executables are generally read-only;)